# LAStools in QGIS 2.8.5: "missing dependency. lastools folder is not configured"

Tags: qgis, installation, error, lidar, lastools

I am using QGIS 2.8.5 Wien and I am trying to install LAStools toolbox. I followed the instructions in [rapidlasso.com](http://rapidlasso.com/2013/09/29/how-to-install-lastools-toolbox-in-qgis/) to install it.

I did everything said on the link, but when I tried to run it, it said:

> missing dependency. this algorithm cannot be run :-( lastools folder is not configured. please configure it before running lastools algorithms.